# How can I constrain a set of coordinates to a circular area?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm making a small game and I have a character that can move in all directions (x and y), and his velocity is stored simply in two integers, `vx` and `vy`. Now, I want to constrain him to a set area, but this area shouldn't be a square, but instead be a circle. I can easily detect when the character is outside the circle with a simple application of the distance formula, but that's not the problem. I'm not sure what to do then. How do I calculate the closest point inside the circle to the out-of-bounds coordinate? And more importantly, how do I figure out how to modify the velocity variables to match this boundary?

So far, I've determined that I can find the closest point on the circle with some simple trigonometry:

```
double angle = Math.atan2(posX, posY);
posX = (int)(Math.cos(angle)/radius);
posY = (int)(Math.sin(angle)/radius);
```

But that seems like it could be improved upon. I'm totally lost about the other element. Help please?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: @Derek – That's all well and good, but it gives me no information on how to actually implement that.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#section_4 shows how to convert to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @Derek – Okay, but I already have that in the code snippet, and it doesn't seem to help with the other part.

Comment: If you express characters location in polar coordinates the solution should be clear.  Simply reduce the distance from where they are until their inside.

Comment: @Derek – Again, that's not the main problem. See my comment on Allen's answer for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to change the velocities,  just let them continually run into the wall.  Just keep moving them back inside the circle whenever they go out.  I imagine the would appear as if they are running around the edge of the circle, until their velocity is perpendicular to the edge of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact values actually work out very nicely, assuming that the center of the circle is at `(0,0)`.

When the character is out of bounds, we bring the character back to the boundary by scaling the old values by `r/D`, where `D=sqrt(x^2+y^2)`:

```
x*=r/D
y*=r/D
```

*Note: this is actually equivalent to your way using trig because*

```
r*cos(tan(y/x))=r*x/sqrt(x^2+y^2)
```

You can then set the velocity to zero, or simulate bumping against the boundary by setting `vx*=k` and `vy*=k`, where `k` is a dampening constant between **-1** and 0.

As an extra touch, you can make the character slow down near the boundary, by

```
vx*=k*[(r-D)/r]
```

That extra term is required since the scale factor is dependent on position: closer to the boundary, we want the speed to be reduced much more. Here, `k` is between 0 and positive 1 since we're only slowing down, not reversing.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I see what you're getting at. However, the main problem with this is that is dampens both velocities equally, all at once. For example, if the character went straight into the right side of the circle, aka (0,1) on the unit circle), `vx` should be dampened but not `vy`. If it's vertical, the inverse would be true, and at a 45 degree angle, they'd be dampened equally. While there cases are simple, it's the in-between arbitrary ones that stump me.

Comment: Good point. You want to apply the dampening factor separately instead - I will edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I gather that you want to figure out if a given position of the object represents a border position - i.e. for example, detect if it cannot move left from this position.

I think the straightforward way would be to have a check function before any move. That is, see if a move is valid with respect to the given position - this can be done by seeing if the result of that action causes the object to go outside the boundary. If the check returns true - you can execute that action. If the check returns false - do not allow that move.